# Query regarding Central Wallets and Sub Wallets

Tags: wallet

Is it possible to develop a wallet system with a central wallet and sub wallet system for Bitcoin and other cryptocurrencies. Is there any wallet system available with such features. Any guidance or pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hardware wallets generally use a master seed from which they generate wallets for each cryptocurrency. One particular specification for this use case is [BIP44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki) (which builds upon [BIP32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki) and [BIP43](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0043.mediawiki)).